# Minesweeper as a Console Application

Tags: c#, console-application

This code is supposed to recreate Minesweeper in the console, but the last method is not called correctly. It should reveal all the surrounding zeros on the field. Where is the error, so that all zeros on the field are uncovered?

```
class Minesweeper
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Willkommen beim Mienenwischen!");
        Console.Write("Auf welcher Spielfeldgröße möchtet du starten (maximal 20x20) ein: ");
        int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (size < 1 || size > 20)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Spielfeldgröße. Das Spielfeld muss zwischen 1x1 und 20x20 liegen.");
            return;
        }

        Console.Write("Wie viele Mienen sollen auf dem Feld versteckt sein: ");
        int mines = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        if (mines < 1 || mines > size * size)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Schaffst du auch Irgendwas? Zähl nach! Es geht nicht");
            return;
        }

        char[,] board = InitializeBoard(size);
        char[,] minePositions = PlaceMines(size, mines);
        bool[,] revealed = new bool[size, size];

        bool gameOver = false;

        while (!gameOver)
        {
            DisplayBoard(board, revealed);

            Console.Write("Gib die Koordianten ein um mögliche Mienen aufzucken (Beispiel: A03): ");
            string input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input.Length != 3 || !char.IsLetter(input[0]) || !char.IsDigit(input[1]) || !char.IsDigit(input[2]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Ungültige Eingabe. Verwende das Format wie Angegeben 'A03'.");
                continue;
            }

            int column = input[0] - 'A';
            int row = int.Parse(input.Substring(1, 2)) - 1;

            if (column < 0 || column >= size || row < 0 || row >= size || revealed[row, column])
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Du bist außerhalb des Spielfelds. Probier es nochmal");
                continue;
            }

            if (minePositions[row, column] == '*')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Tja da war eine Miene, trainiere das Köpfchen und versuche es nochmal.");
                gameOver = true;
            }
            else
            {
                int adjacentMines = CountAdjacentMines(minePositions, row, column);
                board[row, column] = (char)(adjacentMines + '0');
                if (adjacentMines == 0)
                {
                    RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row, column);
                }
 
                if (adjacentMines > 0)
                {
                    revealed[row, column] = true;
                }

                if (CheckWinCondition(board, revealed, mines))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Glückwunsch! Du hast Gewonnen!");
                    gameOver = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static char[,] InitializeBoard(int size)
    {
        char[,] board = new char[size, size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                board[i, j] = '_';
            }
        }
        return board;
    }

    static char[,] PlaceMines(int size, int mines)
    {
        char[,] minePositions = new char[size, size];
        Random rand = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                minePositions[i, j] = ' ';
            }
        }

        while (mines > 0)
        {
            int row = rand.Next(size);
            int col = rand.Next(size);

            if (minePositions[row, col] == ' ')
            {
                minePositions[row, col] = '*';
                mines--;
            }
        }

        return minePositions;
    }

    static void DisplayBoard(char[,] board, bool[,] revealed)
    {
        int size = board.GetLength(0);

        Console.WriteLine("\t" + string.Join(" ", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".Substring(0, size)));
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            Console.Write((i + 1) + "\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (revealed[i, j])
                {
                    Console.Write(board[i, j] + "");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("_");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static int CountAdjacentMines(char[,] minePositions, int row, int col)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int size = minePositions.GetLength(0);

        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++)
            {
                int newRow = row + i;
                int newCol = col + j;

                if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < size && newCol >= 0 && newCol < size && minePositions[newRow, newCol] == '*')
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }


    static bool CheckWinCondition(char[,] board, bool[,] revealed, int mines)
    {
        int size = board.GetLength(0);
        int unrevealedCount = size * size - mines;
        int revealedCount = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
            {
                if (revealed[i, j])
                {
                    revealedCount++;
                }
            }
        }

        return unrevealedCount == revealedCount;
    }

    static void RevealAdjacentZeros(char[,] board, bool[,] revealed, int row, int col)
    {
        int size = board.GetLength(0);
        if (row < 0 || row >= size || col < 0 || col >= size || revealed[row, col])
        {
            return;
        }
        revealed[row, col] = true;

        if (board[row, col] == '_')
        {
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row - 1, col);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row + 1, col);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row, col - 1);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row, col + 1);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row - 1, col - 1);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row - 1, col + 1);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row + 1, col - 1);
            RevealAdjacentZeros(board, revealed, row + 1, col + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to programming and therefore do not have much experience. But I have already tried using `Console.WriteLine` to check if this method is being called at all, and it is. That's why I have no idea where the error could be.

Comment: "aufzucken" is pretty sure a typo, isn't it?

Comment: And "Miene" is a typo too ;o)

Comment: Can I get the exact error you’re getting? Or is it just a bug?